# How to Reset Change Event In Angular

Tags: angular, image, input, file-upload

Consider the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-image-video-preview-final?file=app/app.component.html). If I select an image from my filesystem the image loads without problems. But if I now reload the same image from my filesystem a new event is not raised and the image is not loaded. My question is. What should I do to load the previously uploaded image again? In other words ... how to reset the component's cache so that a new event is emitted and in this way the same image can be loaded twice?

Finally, I would like to know why (change) works this way?

Comment: After  you  push   e.target.result into your mydata array,  you could  use  the following 
 line   .nativeElement.value = "";   This will allow  you to trigger change event  with the repeated file.

Comment: I didn't  explain that very well. First, add a template reference to your file tag. Something like  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInputRef!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>; and  <input #fileInput type="file" accept='image/*'  (change)="onSelectFile($event)">   Afterwards use  this.fileInputRef.nativeElement.value = "";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-upload the same file you need to reset the `event.target.value` :

```
event.target.value = "";
```

here's your example updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-image-video-preview-final-ftzscs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts